# c++ shared_ptr from char* to void*

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to pass a `char *` string to a function which will execute inside a thread. The function has the following prototype:

```
void f(void *ptr);
```

The thread allocation is made by a function similar to the following:

```
void append_task(std::function<void(void *)> &f, void *data);
```

I want to allocate a string that will be used inside the thread. Right Now I have this:

```
string name = "random string";
char *str = new char[name.length()];
strcpy(str, name.c_str());
append_task(f, static_cast<void *>(str));
```

I would like to discard the obligation to allocate and deallocate memory manually . How can I do this with `std::shared_ptr` (namely, the cast to void, and do I guarantee that the string is deallocated when the thread ends?)

P.S. Changing the `append_task()` function IS an option.

Comment: What about changing `append_task` to `void append_task(std::function<void(void *)> &f, std::shared_ptr<void> data)` (with correct deleter) ?

Comment: To be clear, `f` should receive its own copy of the data, for which it is the exclusive owner, and `f` should release the data after the thread has finished executing it?  (You may have to change the design of your program and change the signature of `f` and of `append_task`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ditch the second argument to `append_task`, and make it take a function with no arguments. Then pass the `function` by value, not reference. That way, you can just bind the extra data within a lambda, and count on `std::string` and `std::function` to do the memory management.

Like so:

```
void f(void *ptr);
void append_task(std::function<void()> f);

int main()
{
    std::string name = "random string";
    append_task( [=]{f((void*)name.c_str());} );
}
```

Comment: (*Ignore this comment - I was wrong*) This assumes that the thread completes it execution before the lifetime of `name` completes. (It works in your example only because it's in `main`.) The pointer returned from `.c_str()` could be invalid by the time the task run.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You are wrong, the `=` specifies that `name` is copied into the lambda.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid No, it doesn't. Because the lambda capture is by value (due to the `[=]`), not reference, a separate copy of the string is stored in the closure-type (and hence in the `function`). The variable inside the lambda is called "name", but it's a *different* "name".

Comment: I'll try it! By the way, the reason I am limiting the void function(void *) prototype is because I am storing the functions in a map. Is there a way to store different functions with different prototypes in the same container?

Comment: @manatttta If the `void*` is just being used as the data for the callback function, that's an old C idiom which richly deserves to die now that we have `std::function`, and you can instead bind whatever data is needed into the function. Alternatively, you could keep the function parameter list the same, and just introduce an unused `void*` argument into the lambda.

Comment: @Sneftel so you are saying, store the functions as `void ()`?

Comment: @manatttta Exactly. The introduction of `std::function` removed one of the last reasons to ever use `void*` in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly there is a dangerous bug in your code:

```
char *str = new char[name.length()];
strcpy(str, name.c_str());
```

[`std::string::length`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) returns the size of the string in bytes *excluding the null byte at the end of the string*. Then you copy into this buffer with `strcpy` which reads from a `const char *` until it hits a null byte into your buffer which is now too short to contain the null byte. You then pass this `const char *` into a function which now has no idea how long this array is and is probably assuming it to be a null terminated array. This kind of mistake is so common in C that you really need to avoid directly handling C-style strings as much as humanly possible.

As to how to solve your problem I can't improve on the solution using lambdas that Sneftel provides.